# Github API for c#

Tags: c#, git, github

I am interested in developing a code tool for myself.  I would like to be able to point it at my GitHub repositories and have it download the files directly from GitHub to perform analysis.  I was wondering if anybody knew if Git provides an API for programmers to access repository contents in c#.  Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you even try to search? Putting your exact question title into Google reveals [octokit.net](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net) as the very first result.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a quick look through developer section of GitHub will point you to Octokit, which is a .NET API for GitHub (4.5 and above).

https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net

Comment: Does Octokit access only remote repo? Or can it work with local also?